# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice'). @nestjs/platform-socket.io

Tags: sockets, nestjs

Doesn't work if install all modules, but works if I install only

`@nestjs/platform-socket.io: "9.1.6"` and `@nestjs/websockets: "9.1.6"`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/build/server.js:474
        const listeners = server.listeners("request").slice(0);
                                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
```

Answer (score 3):

reinstall:

```
npm i --save @nestjs/websockets @nestjs/platform-socket.io
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@WebSocketGateway(80,{ cors: true, transports:['websocket'] })
@Injectable()
export class SocketService implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  async handleConnection(socket) {
    console.info(`socket Connected ${socket}`);
  }
  async handleDisconnect(socket) {
    console.info(`socket Disconnected ${socket}`);
  }
}


Provide the Port number this issue will resolve
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and updated versions as below:

"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^8.4.7",

"@nestjs/websockets": "^8.4.7",

it is working with
node v16.14.2
npm v8.5.0